# Can't get Bootstrap Card to align text properly

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a leaderboard sort of thing, this is for something at work.

This is a bootstrap element and I want the numbers to be aligned to the right, the numbers should be vertically aligned. See example of how it currently looks on the image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AuRg.png)

Here is the code, I use EJS to for loop this, hence only 1 instance, I've translated all EJS elements to normal HTML:

```
<div class="card d-flex" style="display: inline-block; width: 350px; float: right; margin-right: 100px;">
    <ul class="list-unstyled card-body mb-0 pb-0">
      <li class="media mb-3">
        <div class="media-body">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <strong style="font-size: 20px;">Jordan</strong>
            <p class="float-right pull-right" style="padding-left: 200px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 650">12</p>
          </div>
          <div class="progress mb-1" style="height: 10px;">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%; background-color: green" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Tried using text-align, float, pull-right, text-right, mt-auto etc. doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't require it for some other reason you can replace `display: inline-block` with `display: flex; justify-content: space-between`

This should space it so it takes up the maximum amount of space between the 2 text elements and the length of the name wont effect the number position :)